# How can I select data from mySQL database and write the code in a good form?

Tags: php

I need to write my php code (for a database selection) in a different way because I am using a different configuration.

This is the original code, which is working fine:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) { 
  echo $row['id'];
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

And this is my new code:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');
query($pdo) -> execute();
$row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($pdo as $row) {
  echo $row['id'];
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

It should work exactly like the original code but there is some mistake, because with the new code I see only the half of my page. Do you have an idea what I did wrong?

---

I tried Tom Hart's suggestion:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');
$pdo->query()->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($pdo as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

But still not working.

Comment: What happens if you try `$pdo->query()->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`? Also, make sure error reporting is turned on, that should give you a clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: `query($pdo) -> execute();`, what's that?

Comment: @TomHart Hello, I tried your suggestion (wrote it in the question) Did you mean it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDO object is stored in `$pdo` variable, yet your proceed to say :

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');
```

which effectively resets the `$pdo` variable to point to something else other than your PDO object.

Your might wana re-factor your code to look like below:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');
$stmt-> execute();
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $id = $row['id'];
   $name = $row['name'];

   echo $id. ' : '. $name; //or whatever you wana do with them
}
```

Comment: foreach will runs only one times since fetch will  select only one row

Comment: Thank you very much, in the for each loop, can I still keep `echo $row['id'];` or do I have to change everything to `echo $val['id'];`

Comment: You could rename `$row` to `$rows`, then rename `$val` to `$row` to keep using `$row` instead of `$val`

Comment: with your code I get results, this is good, but much more then in the database and it is always the same entry, I am confused, why this happened

Comment: You could use a while loop to iterate over the results. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, do you miss a `{`

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, maybe I should write that `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);`

Comment: I assumed you already made a successful database connection. Of course, without it, none of the codes I posted will work.

Comment: Ah, it worked when I changed your code a little bit: `$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only one row , replace it as

```
$res = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC');
$res-> execute();
$rows = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows AS  $row) {
 //your codes here
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, only one row is not working, unfortunately